# Как сравнить строку в Java методом substring

Tags: java, substring

столкнулся с такой проблемой что мне нужно было переписать учебный код с **JavaScript** на **Java**. И я не могу правильно проверить условие в цикле c if. У меня есть массив **car** где он отфильтровывает значения с C100 по условию **if(car[i].substring(0,4) == "100")** но оно почему то не срабатывает, хотя я для проверки занес в **System.out.println(car[0].substring(0,4))**; и у меня прекрасно вывелось С100, но в условии такое почему то не срабатывает.

**Вот мой кода на Java**

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        String[] car = new String[] {"C100_1-100", "C200_1-120-1200", "C300_1-120-30", "C100_2-50"};
        System.out.println(car[0].substring(0,4));
        for(int i = 0; i < car.length; i++){
            if(car[i].substring(0,4) == "C100") {
                System.out.println("Значение с С100");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Другой код");
            }
        }
    }
```

**А вот изначальный рабочий момент на JavaScript где условие проверки удачно проходит**

```
let car = ["C100_1-100", "C200_1-120-1200", "C300_1-120-30", "C400_1-80-20", "C100_2-50"]
for (let i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
    if (car[i].substr(0, 4) == "C100") {
      run_class1.push(car[i].split("-")[1])
      gsm_general.push(car[i].split("-")[1])
 
      car_class1_cost.push(Number(car[i].split("-")[1] * 0.125 * 100 * 0.1 * 4.61))
      car_array_c100.push(car[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Java сравнение строк работает по другому:

```
 if(car[i].substring(0,4).equals("C100")) {
            System.out.println("Значение с С100");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Другой код");
        }
```

Comment: Ну древний же дубликат)

Comment: лень искать дубликаты...